# Which is better, DOMNodeInserted or ajaxStop in respect of efficiency and browser support in my specific situation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to wrap each select element in `<div class="classname"></div>`  when they are inserted in a `div` using ajax call success function, this ajax call is not in my control so I have two options to run the JavaScript wrapSelect function:

**Option-1**

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    $('#hook select').each(function(){
        if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('select-box'))
        {
            wrapSelect($(this));
        }
    });    
});
```

**Option-2**

```
$('#hook').on('DOMNodeInserted', function() {
    $('#hook').off('DOMNodeInserted');
    $('#hook select').each(function(){
        if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('select-box'))
        {
            wrapSelect($(this));
        }
    });  
});
```

Please suggest me which is batter in respect of efficiency and browser support?

**Edit**

Yes, the third option is MutationObserver as mentioned by @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DOMNodeInserted` is slow and [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events):

> This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.
>
> ...
>
> These events are not implemented consistently across different browsers, for example: ...

If you wanted to use something with similar functionality, better to use a MutationObserver, which can do almost the exact same thing, except after a microtask, rather than synchronously.

MutationObserver is pretty old, but it doesn't support *extremely ancient* obsolete browsers like IE10 and below. But that's probably just fine.

If `ajaxStop` works for you too, then that's just fine - as long as you can depend on the page supporting jQuery, it's a perfectly valid choice, without any real downsides.

You *may* find that it's more reliable to check for `ajaxComplete` instead of `ajaxStop`. `ajaxStop` will run after *all* requests have completed, but `ajaxComplete` will run after *any* request completes, so `ajaxComplete` might run faster - *if* that's what you want, of course.

Comment: Thank you @CertainPerformance, There may be many ajax requests running, I don't know the sequence of the ajax requests so I use `ajaxStop`, one thing needs to be considered that is the `wrapSelect` function must run after all the ajax requests are completed and data is inserted to div#hook properly.

Comment: Are you sure that *all* requests need to finish before the element gets populated? If not, it'd be better to examine each request individually (check its endpoint, response, the DOM, etc) to see if it was the request that populated the element, kinda like https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/blob/master/Comment-History-Checker/src/watchForCommentChanges/watchForSelfDeletedComments.ts

Comment: Yes, I am sure that all requests need to finish before the element gets populated?

Comment: Sure, then `ajaxStop` is definitely the right one to use.

Comment: What is the scenario when `ajaxComplete` may fail?

Comment: It's not that it'll *fail* exactly, just that it's not the right tool if you need to wait for all requests to complete - for that situation, which sounds like this one is, it'll run its callback multiple times (when all but the last are unnecessary), when you can use `ajaxStop` instead, which will run its callback once.

Comment: You mean if there are  3 ajax requests `ajaxComplete` will be called 3 times while `ajaxStop` will be called once.

Comment: Thank you very much @CertainPerformance, you are right I need to use `ajaxComplete` instead of `ajaxStop`.

Comment: But I thought you said *I am sure that all requests need to finish before the element gets populated*, in which case `ajaxStop` is the right choice?

Comment: Now I realized that I need to call my function each time when any ajax request is completed.